# Using ant and build.xml error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

When I try to run my program on the GL server, I get an error. Also, we have two packages, one where everything is, and the other is a driver package that has Driver.java in it. It runs the program.

BUILD FAILED
Target "run" does not exist in the project "AutoFill".

Why is this? Here is my build.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
<project basedir="." default="build" name="AutoFill">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.7"/>
<property name="source" value="1.7"/>
<path id="AutoFill.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin"
includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">   
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="AutoFill.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to 
includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse 
 compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
<target name="MaxHeap">
    <java classname="proj3.MaxHeap" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="AutoFill.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="Driver">
    <java classname="driver.Driver" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="AutoFill.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: What is your target and what are your build parameters? It looks like - as it states - you do not have a "run" target.

Comment: I'm not really sure. My driver class drives the whole program, so is that it?

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your `build.xml` here. There are some issues with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="AutoFill">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.7"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.7"/>
    <path id="AutoFill.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>

    <target name="cleanall" depends="clean"/>

    <target name="build"
        depends="build-subprojects, build-project"/>

    <target name="build-subprojects"/>

    <target name="build-project"
        depends="init">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true"
            debuglevel="${debuglevel}"
            destdir="bin"
            includeantruntime="false"
            source="${source}"
            target="${target}">   
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="AutoFill.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- Something happened here... -->
    <target
        description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to "/>
    <!-- includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}"> -->

    <!-- Something happened to the name of this target -->
    <target name="init-"
        description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins"
                includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins"
                includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>

    <!-- Something happened to this target name -->
    <target name="build-eclipse compiler"
        description="compile project with Eclipse compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="MaxHeap">
        <java classname="proj3.MaxHeap"
            failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="AutoFill.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="Driver">
        <java classname="driver.Driver"
            failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="AutoFill.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

I don't know if you miscopied it, but it's simply not a valid Ant build file as it stands now. You may want to check your post and see if you missed anything.

Your error is pretty straight forward. You don't have a target named `run`. I have no idea why you would be executing it. (Maybe it's in the section of your `build.xml` that was messed up.

The valid targets are:

- init
- clean
- cleanall
- build
- build-project
- build-subprojects
- init-???  (Target name is not complete)
- build-eclipse compiler (Invalid target name. Can't contain a space)
- MaxHeap (Java Executable)
- Driver (Java Executable)

If you're attempting to compile this project, you want to run the `build-project` or `build` target and not `run`. (Both `build-project` and `build` do the same thing).

If you're attempting to run some program, `MaxHeap` and `Driver` are the only two Java executable targets in the `build.xml`.

So, you probably want to execute the targets `build` and then `Driver` or `MaxHeap`.

Comment: I had Eclipse build me a build.xml. I think that's what the problem is.

Comment: I saw that it was an Eclipse built file. I reformatted it, so I could read it. That's when I found several issues with what you published.

Comment: Is there anyway to get Eclipse to build me one that is correct?

Comment: I don't know. I'm a CM and not a developer. I know Eclipse has its own build algorithm, so it doesn't need an Ant build file for it to build and deploy. I know that you can generate a build.xml by Eclipse, but we usually write our own.

Comment: @user2161813 What did you use in Eclipse to create the build.xml?

Comment: I went to export and then clicked on ant build files.